# EJB and container getting different database connections under Glassfish

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, xa

I have an issue relating to EJBs and their use of database connections under Glassfish, and I can't understand why I can't find plenty of others hitting the same issue, but all my searching has proved fruitless. I would assume this to be more of a Glassfish than a Hibernate question, but hopefully someone can advise on here.

I have a relatively simple setup which is a Hibernate based application using CMT deployed under Glassfish. I have a couple of routes into this application, GUI and WS, and both come in through an EJB call. In order to facilitate multiple EJBs running within a single transaction, I've setup an Oracle XADataSource in a Glassfish connection pool. This all works well except I notice one thing which has caused problems for us. The issue is that any database interactions via the EJB consistently interact with the same underlying connection (which is great), but as soon as the container takes over for the commit, it consistently receives a different connection. A flush at the end of any EJB work can avoid any issues, but if any work is left unflushed on EJB completion and is handled instead by the final commit, this now happens under a different (isolated) connection.

It would seem odd to me that the container would want a different connection to the rest of the transaction, but having debugged in the Glassfish code it seems to very purposefully behave like this. At commit, the connection in use by the EJB is marked as busy and unavailable as a free resource. The allocation this time round is not against the transaction, so simply looks to pick up a free resource, which will be a different connection.

This is a bit of an issue for us as we're building a framework in which it cannot be guaranteed that the last call in an EJB method will be a flush.

I'd be most grateful if someone could enlighten me on what's going on here. I really can't understand why this isn't more of a problem for more people. Thanks

Using Glassfish 3.1.1, Hibernate 3.5.6, Oracle driver ojdbc6.jar and javax.sql.XADataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging in the Glassfish source code I understand this a little better now. There is an option in Glassfish to ensure the connection issued to the CMT commit is the same one used throughout the transaction. This setting is in the advanced tab of the connection properties and is called 'Allow Non Component Callers'. The documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jdbc.htm#gavro suggets that third party persistence managers would require this so that 'the returned connection is automatically enlisted with the transaction context obtained from the transaction manager'.

The reason I discovered this was that I deployed another Hibernate based webapp to Glassfish with a much simpler setup, and this time the behaviour was different, and I could see that the datasource name had automatically been suffixed with __pm which is the same as enabling 'Allow Non Component Callers'. The only bit that remains a mystery to me is why one webapp I have triggers this behaviour automatically, and the other doesn't.